# How can I append something, disclaimer-like, to outgoing emails?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'd like to append something to emails going between Notes users (not going to users outside our Domino environment).  As far as I know, the Domino disclaimer function doesn't work between Notes users.  Besides 3rd part solutions, is there a way to implement this?

thanks
clem

Comment: What about a pre delivery agent that runs on each mail file that appends the image if the sender and all recipients are within your domain?  This would involve a fair bit of work and testing

Comment: hmmm... Would it have to run from the mail.box dbs?

Comment: No.  Best place would be on the mail file template.  Docs in the mail.box are transient at best

Comment: hmmm... Looks like there's a querySend event.  I could use that. Thanks!

Comment: I thought about adding a small image to the outgoing email.  Since it's possible that the user composing the email is on a local replica, I figured I'd add the image to the database/template file resources.  To get to the image, I thought I would use the NotesNoteCollection.  Even tho I set everything to false except SelectImageResources, it took 'forever' for the BuildCollection to finish.  So even tho you limit the collection, looks like it just cycles through them all.  Can't use this solution.

Comment: Could you give us a little more info on what the image is for?  There may be other ways to handle this.

Comment: Hi Rob... well, we've been getting a number of 'imposter' emails -- those that appear to be from someone in-house but is just spam or phishing email.  My 'brilliant' ;-) idea to make it simple for someone to determine if the email is legit would be to simply look at the bottom of the email and see if some special image is there.  Or it could be some other visual cue. .  ... Clem

Comment: Ah.  In that case, use the QuerySend to stamp a field with a value e.g. legitMail="1" when the mail is internal only.  Then on the memo/reply forms have an icon below the subject line that is shown or hidden based on this value.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct - you can assign a disclaimer via a policy document but this appends the disclaimer only on outgoing SMTP mail.

For internal email to have a mandatory disclaimer you will need to implement a signature management solution such as CrossWare (https://www.crossware.co.nz/). You cannot rely on users adding a disclaimer to their signature as this can be changed.

Comment: Hi Steven.  Thanks for the reply.  I know about Crossware but it's way beyond what I want to do.  I just want to add a small icon to email going around within our company.  Thanks. Clem